# AcceptTcpClient() and class based on TcpClient

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, tcpclient

I needed a class that would have everything TcpClient has + a couple extra fields so I created a class based on TcpClient:

```
public class MyClient: TcpClient
{
    public string winUser;
    public bool needHelp;
    public bool needSignOff;

    public MyClient() : base() {
        this.needHelp = false;
        this.needSignOff = false;
        this.winUser = "empty";
    }
}
```

Now I need all incoming connections to be created as objects of this class:

```
MyClient clientConnection = (MyClient)this.helpServer.AcceptTcpClient();
```

The problem is that AcceptTcpClient() generates a TcpClient class object and I keep getting this exception when I try to connect to server:

listenServer(): Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient' to type 'Server.MyClient'.

How do I convert a TcpClient object that AcceptTcpClient() gives me into MyClient object?

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to downcast a type (`TcpClient`) to a more derived type (`MyClient`).  You have to update `AcceptTcpClient` to return a `MyClient` object.

Comment: Can you write this as an extension `AcceptTcpMyClient` etc, if you wanted to? And if so are there any details about how to get the source?